# Integrating Numeric Keypad in Webpage using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, numeric, keypad

I have a webpage [here](http://we-think.org/questionnew/) in which I have kept a texbox under Answer: so that user can enter numbers using the numeric Keypad. The Numeric Keypad opens once clicked in the text box.

My problems are:

1. I want to keep advance buttons for inputing Data in forms of Fraction and square, squreroot etc. Is it possible using Jquery?
2. Now if i clicked on the text box the numeric keypad opens and to close it I will have to click in the text box again. But I want to close the textbox by clicking outside of it.

Below is my jquery coding which I took from:
https://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/cdmej/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#numBox').click(function(){
    $('#keypad').fadeToggle('fast');
    event.stopPropagation();
    //alert("The element1 was clicked.");
});


// Function commented out
// due to Chrome apparently being the
// only browser smart enough to work
// right >.<

//$('body').click(function(){
//    $('#keypad').fadeOut('fast');
//    event.stopPropagation();
//});

$('.key').click(function(){
    var numBox = document.getElementById('numBox');
    if(this.innerHTML == '0'){
        if (numBox.innerHTML.length > 0)
            numBox.innerHTML = numBox.innerHTML + this.innerHTML;
    }
    else
        numBox.innerHTML = numBox.innerHTML + this.innerHTML;

    event.stopPropagation();
    //alert("The element2 was clicked.");
});

$('.btn').click(function(){
    if(this.innerHTML == 'DEL'){
        var numBox = document.getElementById('numBox');
        if(numBox.innerHTML.length > 0){
            numBox.innerHTML = numBox.innerHTML.substring(0, numBox.innerHTML.length - 1);
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('numBox').innerHTML = '';
    }

    event.stopPropagation();
    //alert("The element3 was clicked.");
   });
});
```

Comment: For question number one. Yes, it is possible, using `JavaScript`, `Math.sqrt();`. And for the click outside part, you can use `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Thanks, but I want to add a button in numeric keypad for square and all that. How to do?